# NXDOMAIN with CNAME RR in ANSWER section

Tags: domain-name-system

If I resolve `console.aws.amazon.com` with `dig`, I get:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> console.aws.amazon.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 35338
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;console.aws.amazon.com.        IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
console.aws.amazon.com. 4   IN  CNAME   lbr-optimized.console-l.amazonaws.com.
lbr-optimized.console-l.amazonaws.com. 4 IN CNAME us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com.
us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com. 4 IN  CNAME   gr.console-geo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
gr.console-geo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 4 IN CNAME console.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.
console.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 59 IN  A   54.239.30.25
```

However, when resolving `us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com` it gets an `NXDOMAIN`:

```
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 33652
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com. 60 IN CNAME   gr.console-geo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 60 IN  SOA ns-912.amazon.com. root.amazon.com. 1609664924 3600 900 7776000 60

;; Received 147 bytes from 52.9.146.37#53(ns-912.amazon.com) in 270 ms
```

It looks like, even if we have a `NXDOMAIN` as response code, it continues to resolve the CNAME. However, according to the RFC (I have seen that in #8020), if there is a `NXDOMAIN` as response code, it means the domain at the end of the chain does not exist, so we are suppose to continue since we are not going to get any A RR...

I'm a bit confused here why we have a `NXDOMAIN` in middle of the chain. Is it safe to ignore the `NXDOMAIN` if we have a `CNAME` in the ANSWER section and continue to resolve the chain of CNAME?

Is there a RFC that solve this kind of question?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Exactly what commands did you run? What is the _complete_ output?

Comment: try `dig @ns-912.amazon.com us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com` to reproduce it - you will get NXDOMAIN with a CNAME in the ANSWER section

Comment: Indeed. That is truly bizarre behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CNAME` (answer) + `SOA` (authority) + `NXDOMAIN` (rcode) type of answer is valid provided that the server actually knows the status of the canonical name (the `CNAME` "target").
In this case it appears that the nameserver for `aws.amazon.com` is set up to also have a `us-east-1.amazonaws.com` zone (the zone where this CNAME leads) where it looks and concludes that the canonical name does not exist. The issue is that this is not the actual `us-east-1.amazonaws.com` zone that the world uses, the real delegation for `us-east-1.amazonaws.com` leads to entirely different nameservers.

Looking at the relevant answer (from the question), do note the `SOA` in the authority section (part of the negative response) and how that is from the "fake" `us-east-1.amazonaws.com` zone at `ns-912.amazon.com`:

```
$ dig @ns-912.amazon.com us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.11.25-RedHat-9.11.25-2.fc33 <<>> @ns-912.amazon.com us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 19359
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com. IN   A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com. 60 IN CNAME   gr.console-geo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 60     IN      SOA     ns-912.amazon.com. root.amazon.com. 1609723312 3600 900 7776000 60

;; Query time: 152 msec
;; SERVER: 52.9.146.37#53(52.9.146.37)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 04 01:21:54 UTC 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 147

$
```

The "real" `us-east-1.amazonaws.com` is delegated elsewhere entirely (not `ns-912.amazon.com`):

```
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      ns2.p31.dynect.net.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      ns4.p31.dynect.net.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      pdns5.ultradns.info.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      pdns3.ultradns.org.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      ns1.p31.dynect.net.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      ns3.p31.dynect.net.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      pdns1.ultradns.net.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      u2.amazonaws.com.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      u6.amazonaws.com.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      u3.amazonaws.com.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      u5.amazonaws.com.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      u1.amazonaws.com.
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 86400  IN      NS      u4.amazonaws.com.
```

and has a completely different SOA:

```
us-east-1.amazonaws.com. 900    IN      SOA     dns-external-master.amazon.com. root.amazon.com. 8548 180 60 2592000 5
```

As for things working relatively well despite this blatant misconfiguration, I believe resolvers simply see through this claimed `NXDOMAIN`, as resolvers are generally good at only trusting "in bailiwick" data in responses.
Ie, not trusting additional data in a response that makes claims about names belonging to zones that are not actually hosted at that nameserver.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I now understand the issue. I still have a slight doubt about why it is working for most of the resolvers. Do the resolvers ignore the `NXDOMAIN` because the `CNAME` is hosted in a different zone? Because if they do trust the `NXDOMAIN`, they would not resolve `console.aws.amazon.com`.

Comment: @vinz Something like that. The name you asked for was clearly not NXDOMAIN itself (the answer section immediately proves that wrong), and the canonical name is in a different zone that doesn't seem to be delegated to this same nameserver.